# Panel dock Manager for angular - does one exist

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am looking for a DockManager in angular similar to ones for react such as https://ticlo.github.io/rc-dock/. I know there are some paid component libraries that offer such components such as [infragistics](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/dock-manager) but I am looking for just the dock manager and not the whole component package. I'd prefer not to go down the line of creating my own, or migrating the whole codebase to react. Anyone know of something that works for angular (and is up to date)

TIA